# Regarding the direction of $\vec{\tau}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

It's said that the direction of $\vec{\tau}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$. I am wondering what if $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$ don't lie on the same plane, then wouldn't it be that no vector could be perpendicular to both $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$ at the same time?

Comment: just so you realize, the other answers only apply to 2-dimensional vectors. Two 3-dimensional vectors don't necessarily lie in the same plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$ are both vectors, so they form a plane... meaning that they always lie in the same plane.

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors *always* lie on the same plane of course.

What you mean is when the two vectors aren't perpendicular, what happens then?

Well, either $\vec{r}$ or$\vec{F}$ can always be decomposed in two components, one component will be perpendicular to the other vector, the other component will be parallel to the other vector.

[image: Two vectors]